# multiple VirtualHosts in different HD partitions

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have apache installed in the main partition (C:) where the SO (W8) is installed  and I want to set another virtual hosts for stored projects placed in different partition (E:). Here's my attempt:

file httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\www"
<Directory "C:\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

file httpd-vhosts.conf
Virtual host num 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory "C:\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy all

    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule . index.php
  </Directory>

  DocumentRoot "C:\www"
  ServerName www.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual host num 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory "E:\workspace\project\php\app">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy all

    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule . index.php
  </Directory>

  DocumentRoot "E:\workspace\project\php\app"
  ServerName workspace.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

and I get the Error 403 "You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you make sure apache can read your e:\ stuff?

Comment: Right click the folder `E:\workspace\project\php\app` and make sure `read-only` is not checked or apache won't like it, **or** you could simple check the folder `C:\www` and replicate the same user access and other properties set to it.

Comment: both have, apparently, the same security properties. The server is in c:\xampp